# Can I setup Git to tell me each time a certain file(s) has been modified

Tags: java, eclipse, git

Is it possible to set Git up in a way that it will tell me when a choice file(s) has been modified. I would like this to be setup similarly to a git hook, but I don't need to know when anything in the whole project has been changed only a choice file.

This is for a Java project that I am running in eclipse.

**Edit**
I have been considering this and am wondering if it is possible to accomplish this without putting in a Git hook that all other developers will need to run. I realize that might not be possible, if it is not possible I will accept the more standard answer.

Comment: @SparshKhandelwal choice file(s) = one or more files in a project. For example if I wanted to know every time some developer pushed a change to a controller or a config file. How would I do this in an automated way?

Comment: How would you want to be notified?

Comment: @chepner email would be my first choice, but other conventional methods like RSS would be fine.

Comment: Did you ever encounter an alternative solution?

Comment: @Scott'scm6079' thanks for doubling back! I never found an alternative way. Seems like a CI solution like Jenkins might be possible though I have not had the time to devote. Until such time as a better solution is found I'm going with your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook the whole directory (e.g. pre commit), and then filter to get just the file(s) you want.

```
my_files=$(git status --short | grep -E '^(A|M)' | awk '{ print $2 }' | grep -E 'WhateverPatternYouNeed\.php$')

for file in $my_files; do
  # Do something... 
done
```

Of course your "do-something" can make a curl call to text you, email, etc.